# How to use data from main.m in a subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am doing homework from the Big Nerd Ranch Guide book. In the problem, I have two arrays in main.m. One is from a subclass and the other from a superclass. BNRItem is the superclass. BNRContainer is the subclass. In the implementation files I have description string which says what the NSLog should say. I need to take the data from the superclass used in main.m's array and use it in the subclass so that the subclass array can work. is there an easy answer?
In main.m I have the following:

```
//  main.m
//  RandomItems

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRItem.h"
#import "BNRContainer.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            BNRItem *item = [BNRItem randomItem];
            [items addObject:item];
        }

        for (BNRItem *item in items) {
            NSLog(@"%@", item);
        }

        NSMutableArray *containers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            BNRContainer *container = [BNRContainer randomContainer];
            [containers addObject:container];
        }

        for (BNRContainer *container in containers) {
            NSLog(@"%@", container);
        }

        items = nil;
        containers = nil;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In BNRItem.h:

```
//  BNRItem.h
//  RandomItems
//
//  Created by Meghan on 3/19/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Meghan. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BNRItem : NSObject
{
    NSString *_itemName;
    NSString *_serialNumber;
    int _valueInDollars;
    NSDate *_dateCreated;
}

+ (instancetype)randomItem;

//Designated initializer for BNRItem
- (instancetype)initWithItemName:(NSString *)name
                  valueInDollars:(int)value
                    serialNumber:(NSString *)sNumber;

-(instancetype)initWithItemName:(NSString *)name;

- (NSString *)description;


- (void)setItemName:(NSString *)str;
-( NSString *)itemName;

- (void)setSerialNumber:(NSString *)str;
- (NSString *)serialNumber;

- (void)setValueInDollars:(int)v;
- (int)valueInDollars;

- (NSDate *)dateCreated;
@end
```

in BNRContainer.h:

```
//  BNRContainer.h
//  RandomItems
//
//  Created by Meghan on 3/20/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Meghan. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BNRItem.h"

@interface BNRContainer : BNRItem
{
    NSString *_containerName;
    int _containerItemsSum;
    int _containerValue;
    int _totalContainerValue;
}

- (NSString *)description;

+ (instancetype)randomContainer;

//Designated initializer for BNRContainer
- (instancetype)initWithContainerName:(NSString *)name
                  containerItemsSum:(int)iSum
                    containerValue:(int)value
                totalContainerValue:(int)tvalue;

- (instancetype)initWithContainerName:(NSString *)name;

- (instancetype)init;

- (void)setContainerName:(NSString *)str;
- (NSString *)containerName;
- (void)setContainerItemsSum:(int)v;
- (int)containerItemsSum;
- (void)setContainerValue:(int)v;
- (int)containerValue;
- (void)setTotalContainerValue:(int)v;
- (int)totalContainerValue;


@end
```

The variable containerItemsSum in BNRContainer should be the sum of valueInDollars of several items and the value is generated in main.m when it is looped through.

```
//  BNRItem.m
//  RandomItems
//
//  Created by Meghan on 3/19/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Meghan. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BNRItem.h"

@implementation BNRItem

- (instancetype)initWithItemName:(NSString *)name
                  valueInDollars:(int)value
                    serialNumber:(NSString *)sNumber
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        //Give the instance variables initial values
        _itemName = name;
        _serialNumber = sNumber;
        _valueInDollars = value;
        //Set dateCreated to the current date and time
        _dateCreated = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    }
                        return self;
}

-(instancetype)initWithItemName:(NSString *)name
{
    return [self initWithItemName:name
                   valueInDollars:0
                     serialNumber:@""];
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    return [self initWithItemName:@"Item"];
}

+ (instancetype)randomItem
{
    NSArray *randomAdjectiveList = @[@"Fluffy", @"Rusty", @"Shiny"];
    NSArray *randomNounList = @[@"Bear", @"Spork", @"Mac"];
    NSInteger adjectiveIndex = arc4random() % [randomAdjectiveList count];
    NSInteger nounIndex = arc4random() % [randomNounList count];

    NSString *randomName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                            randomAdjectiveList[adjectiveIndex],
                            randomNounList[nounIndex]];
    int randomValue = arc4random() % 100;
    NSString *randomSerialNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c%c%c%c",
                                    '0' + arc4random() % 10,
                                    'A' + arc4random() % 26,
                                    '0' + arc4random() % 10,
                                    'A' + arc4random() % 26,
                                    '0' + arc4random() % 10];
    BNRItem *newItem = [[self alloc] initWithItemName:randomName
                                       valueInDollars:randomValue
                                         serialNumber:randomSerialNumber];
    return newItem;
}


- (void)setItemName:(NSString *)str
{
    _itemName = str;
}
- (NSString *)itemName
{
    return _itemName;
}

- (void)setSerialNumber:(NSString *)str
{
    _serialNumber = str;
}

- (NSString *)serialNumber
{
    return _serialNumber;
}

- (void)setValueInDollars:(int)v
{
    _valueInDollars = v;
}

- (int)valueInDollars
{
    return _valueInDollars;
}

- (NSDate *)dateCreated
{
    return _dateCreated;
}



- (NSString *)description
{
    NSString *descriptionString =
    [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ (%@): Worth $%d, recorded on %@",
        self.itemName,
        self.serialNumber,
        self.valueInDollars,
        self.dateCreated];
    return descriptionString;
}

@end
```

Comment: which data are you exactly supposed to take from BNRItem?

Comment: the values of the items. One of the values in BNRContainer is the sum of the values of several items.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you include the header files of BNRItem and BNRContainer? What is the code above supposed to do? At the moment you just make two arrays, then log out the contents of each object in each array. The two have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @jrturton: one of the variables of BNRItem is needed for a variable in BNRContainer. Let's say BNRItem loops three times & I get three values for valueInDollars. I need to add those three numbers for the variable  containerItemsSum which is used in the second loop for BNRContainer.

Comment: It seems odd that BNRContainer doesn't actually have the ability to, well, _contain_ anything. All it does is add a few properties. I'd have expected you to make some BNRItems and then contain them in a BNRContainer

Comment: @jrturton: I've uploaded BNRItem.m so you can see that there are items for BNRContainer to contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (BNRItem *item in items) {
        NSLog(@"%@", item);
    }
```

Here, you're passing through each `BNRItem` that you've created. This is your opportunity to collect information about the items.

Create a local variable to store the total, and add to it each item you read:

```
int dollarTotal = 0;    
for (BNRItem *item in items) {
    NSLog(@"%@", item);
    dollarTotal += [item valueInDollars];
}
NSLog(@"Total value in dollars is %d",dollarTotal);
```

You'd then use this value to set the total for the container, although this seems completely backward. A `BNRContainer` should (though this may be a later point in the tutorial you are doing) be able to derive this total from its own set of contained items, using a loop similar to the one above. I don't see why you are creating three containers in a loop either. The example doesn't make a great deal of sense.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use dollarTotal in BNRContainer.m? I'm creating three containers because each container contains three items.

Comment: It doesn't at the moment, that's my confusion. I'd expect the container to have an initWithItems: method, and you to pass in an array of items. Otherwise, you'd use that value derived above to set the dollar value on a container. I think you've either missed something important from the tutorial, or the tutorial is missing something important.

Comment: got it. Thanks @jrturton, I'll mark your answer as the answer as there is no answer.